# Proxy is built for deleted strip instead of short segment

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Using hard-cuts I selected a small segment of a longer strip.  (The longer strip is no longer in my sequencer; I deleted it.)  Then I chose a 50% proxy and did a "rebuild proxy".  All is fine.  But when I look at the actual proxy avi file in the proxy folder, I see that it is for the original (i.e. full-length strip) which I had deleted, not just the small segment I have in my sequencer.  Is this normal, or would this be a bug?  (Prior to this, I know I did not have any proxies built, because the proxy folder did not exist.)

Had the proxy been built for the short segment only, it would have taken much shorter to build.

Answer (score 2):

This would be typical behaviour, as a hard cut trim is a rarely used feature. Great for making freeze frames but not very flexible. More often a user would make a soft cut to allow later alteration, in which case you would want all of the proxy to be available.

Also I imagine that transcoding the entire original media would eliminate the potential for mismatched frames of long GOP (Group of Pictures) sources. Where Blender actually has to decode all of the previous frames to make sure that it creates the correct ones that you have selected to hard cut on.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't understand the part about its use for freeze frames, as I am new to both Blender and video editing.

Comment: When you use a Hard Cut in blender you are placing a hard limit on frames available from that particular clip. If you drag the handles of that clip past the defined limit it will just continue to play the last frame as a still image. Effectively freezing the shot.